Why does SymPy give eigenvectors for a degenerate subspace that dont form valid projection operators?
I am trying to use SymPy to symbolically calculate each set of projection operators corresponding to the eigen subspaces of each of the matrices defined in the list An:
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
qutritketsn = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
qutritketss = sp.Matrix(qutritketsn)
an = [(1/sp.sqrt(1+sp.cos(sp.pi/5)))*(sp.cos(4*sp.pi*n/5)*qutritketss.col(0)+sp.sin(4*sp.pi*n/5)*qutritketss.col(1)+sp.sqrt(sp.cos(sp.pi/5))*qutritketss.col(2)) for n in range(5)]
An = [sp.eye(3)-2*(v*v.T.conjugate()) for v in an]

Note that the matrices in An should all have eigenvalues -1, 1, 1.
The code I have to do this is the following:
eigproj = []
for num in range(len(An)):
    eig_stuff = An[num].eigenvects(simplify=True)
    eigproj_temp = []
    for i in range(len(eig_stuff)):
        if eig_stuff[i][1]<2:
            evnorm = eig_stuff[i][2][0].normalized()
            proj = evnorm*evnorm.T.conjugate()
            eigproj_temp.append(proj)
        else: # sum the projectors to get the projector for the degenerate subspace
            shp = eig_stuff[i][2][0].shape
            init = sp.zeros(shp[0], shp[0])
            for j in range(len(eig_stuff[i][2])):
                evnorm1 = eig_stuff[i][2][j].normalized()
                init += evnorm1*evnorm1.T.conjugate()
            eigproj_temp.append(init)

Now the problem is that the eigenvectors corresponding to the degenerate eigenvalues that are returned in eig_stuff do not give valid projection operators when they are first normalized, then each projection operator is calculated and summed together.
I tested this extensively by checking if the resulting projection operators were idempotent, if they were orthogonal to the projection operator corresponding to the non-degenerate eigenvalue, and if both projection operators summed to the identity; all tests failed. The projection operator corresponding to the non-degenerate eigenvalue is idempotent, which is why I suspect the problem is with the projection operator corresponding to the degenerate eigenvalues.
Furthermore, I am fairly certain this is an issue related to SymPy because the eigenvectors returned by the equivalent NumPy code can be used to form valid projection operators. Here is the NumPy code for reference (using the NumPy version of An as well):
from collections import Counter
        eigproj = []
        for num in range(len(An)):
            eigs_temp, eigvs_temp = np.linalg.eigh(An[num])
            # Eigenvalues should be integers, so round any floats that are close enough to an integer
            for i in range(len(eigs_temp)):
                if np.abs(eigs_temp[i].real-np.round(eigs_temp[i].real)) < 10**(-13):
                    temps = np.round(eigs_temp[i].real)
                    eigs_temp.real[i] = temps    
            eig_mult = Counter(eigs_temp) # counts the eigenvalue multiplicities
            eig_mult = list(eig_mult.values())
            # get indices of eigenvalues according to multiplicities
            dup_inds = [[k for k in range(int(int(i>0)*sum([eig_mult[j] for j in range(max(i, 0))])), sum([eig_mult[j] for j in range(i+1)]))] for i in range(len(eig_mult))]
            eigproj_temp = [np.outer(eigvs_temp[:, i], np.conj(eigvs_temp[:, i])) for i in range(eigvs_temp.shape[0])]
            eigproj_temp1 = []
            for i in dup_inds:
                # sum the projectors to get the projector for the degenerate subspace
                if len(i)>1:
                    og = np.zeros(eigproj_temp[0].shape)
                    for j in i:
                        og += eigproj_temp[j]
                    eigproj_temp1.append(og)
                else:
                    eigproj_temp1.append(eigproj_temp[i[0]])

            eigproj_temp1 = np.array(eigproj_temp1)
            eigproj.append(eigproj_temp1)

Here is an example output for the second set of projection operators corresponding to the matrix
Matrix([
[0.27639320225002103036, 0.52573111211913360603, 0.80449586419071039205],
[0.52573111211913360603, 0.61803398874989484820, -0.58450045893897621288],
[0.80449586419071039205, -0.58450045893897621288, 0.10557280900008412144]
])

using SymPy evaluated with 20 digits of precision:
# For eigenvalue -1
Matrix([
[0.36180339887498948482, -0.26286555605956680301, -0.40224793209535519602],
[-0.26286555605956680301, 0.19098300562505257590, 0.29225022946948810644],
[-0.40224793209535519602, 0.29225022946948810644, 0.44721359549995793928]
])

# For degenerate eigenvalue 1
Matrix([
[0.89827790731256834867, 0.47552825814757678606, 0.49720578787857844011],
[0.47552825814757678606, 0.65450849718747371205, 0],
[0.49720578787857844011, 0, 0.44721359549995793928]
])

and then with NumPy:
# For eigenvalue -1
array([
[ 0.3618034 , -0.26286556, -0.40224793],
[-0.26286556,  0.19098301,  0.29225023],
[-0.40224793,  0.29225023,  0.4472136 ]
])

# For degenerate eigenvalue 1
array([
[ 0.6381966 ,  0.26286556,  0.40224793],
[ 0.26286556,  0.80901699, -0.29225023],
[ 0.40224793, -0.29225023,  0.5527864 ]
])

So my questions are why is SymPy returning these specific eigenvectors and is the problem really on my end or with SymPy? If it is on my end, what am I doing wrong here? Anyone's help would be greatly appreciated :)

You have made your explanation too long and with too much code: someone else may bother to read it but I won't. Just pick one simple matrix and show what the matrix is and how you get different values between numpy and sympy or something.

@OscarBenjamin Ah sorry just wanted to be thorough. If I show the second set of projection operators using evalf(20) and the NumPy version, would that be enough?

@OscarBenjamin Okay I got rid of the full eigproj output and just put the output for the second set of projection operators using SymPy then NumPy, at the end. Hopefully that is more readable.

It is still too long. What I can say is that the matrix shown has a two-dimensional eigenspace for eigenvalue 1 which means that there is no unique choice for what the eigenvectors would be even up to scalar multiplication. It should not be expected then that sympy and numpy would return the same pair of eigenvectors. It should also not be expected that approximate floating point calculations will be able to handle degenerate cases like this correctly.

@OscarBenjamin I dont expect them to be the same but I do expect eigenvectors that can form valid projectors. I actually found the answer to the problem though: the eigenvectors that sympy returns for the degenerate eigenvalues are not orthogonal. After I orthogonalized them everything seems to be running smoothly. I think it would be worthwhile to emphasize this in the documentation or add the ability to return orthogonalized eigenvectors in the code, so that other users wont be confused.

Orthogonalising the vectors is not something that should be done by default with symbolic eigenvectors because it leads to expression blowup. There could be an option for it though. In general there is no guarantee that eigenvectors can be orthogonal but I think this is often surprising for people who are used to working only with symmetric/hermitian matrices. The numpy function eigh that you use is specifically for this case whereas sympy's eigenvects is for general square matrices.
